# How to put Rows And Columns in center of a Section

Tags: html, css, rows

I'm learning HTML and I'm working on this project where basically I'm trying to show 8 pictures inside a `section` with 4 each in one row. To solve this problem, I looked up how to make rows and columns without using Table (I'm not allowed to for this project).
I came across this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2>Four Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used this trick and made two Rows to solve my problem. I put these two Rows inside a `<section>` I created myself called `gallery1`:

```css
.gallery1 {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Using above code, final code looks like this:

```css
.whitetitle {
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: #4AB19A;
}

.gallery1 {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.gallery1 img {
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.column {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class=" green gallery1">

  <h2 class="whitetitle"> Graphic Designing </h2>


  <section class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

So it turned out good and all but I have a problem! I want the pictures to be in the center, horizontally and vertically. To be exact, I want the title and two rows to be in center, both ways.

I tried the following

```css
 align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
```

Inside the Gallery in CSS but it didn't work. can anyone help me on this please? what should I have done to fix/avoid this.

Also, I tried `flex-box` thing and put `display: flex;` inside Gallery but it shows everything (title and two rows) in one row which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have two sections you can simply wrap them into one section and give it class called `main` then apply the `flex-box` centralization on it.

Here is an Example

```css
.whitetitle {
  color: white;
}

.main {
  background-color: #4AB19A;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.green {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4AB19A;
}

.gallery1 {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.gallery1 img {
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.column {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <section class=" green gallery1">
    <h2 class="whitetitle"> Graphic Designing </h2>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Or you can simply achieve it with the `grid-box` the following is an example

```css
.whitetitle {
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: #4AB19A;
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery1 {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.gallery1 img {
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.column {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class=" green gallery1">
  <h2 class="whitetitle"> Graphic Designing </h2>
  <section class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

All lines marked with `/* <-- */` are new.

```css
.whitetitle {
  color: white;
    margin-left: auto; /* <-- */
    margin-right: auto; /* <-- */
    text-align: center; /* <-- */
}

.green {
  background-color: #4AB19A;
}

.gallery1 {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
    display: flex; /* <-- */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* <-- */
    align-items: center; /* <-- */
  justify-content: center; /* <-- */
}

.gallery1 img {
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.column {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class=" green gallery1">

  <h2 class="whitetitle"> Graphic Designing </h2>


  <section class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yX7UIXh.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```